# Добавление текста в место расположения курсора

Tags: c#

Всем привет.

У меня есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую в richTextBox должен добавиться текст, так вот как можно добавить текст **именно** в то место, где был курсор? Т.е. где он был + текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то вот так:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText =" текст ";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.